# Left-censoring , $Y_i=\text{max}(T_i,U_i)$

Tags: self-study, survival, censoring

In the book , [Statistical Models and Methods for Lifetime Data](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471372153) , in `Left-censoring` , it is written that

> Can only observe $Y_i=\text{max}(T_i,U_i)$ .

Where ,

$T_i$ is the lifetime and $U_i$ is the censoring time .

- But I don't understand why is it `max` of $T_i$ and $U_i$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For *left censoring*, if $T_i$ occurs *before* the time you started observing, then you only see $U_i$, the time you began observing.

$$ T_i \leq U_i \Rightarrow Y_i = U_i $$

Otherwise, $T_i$ occurs *after* you begin observing, and you see $T_i$ itself.

$$ T_i \geq U_i \Rightarrow Y_i = T_i $$

In both cases you end up with the larger of the two, that is, the maximum.

For *right censoring* the roles of *before* and *after* get switched, so all the inequalities reverse. Consequently, the maximum becomes a minimum.

Comment: Not understood your first line . If the event occur for ith individual before I started observing  , then I only see $U_i$ ? Is the definition of your $U_i$ censoring time or time when we started to observe ?

Comment: For *left* censoring, those are the same concept.  The censoring time is the time we started to observe.  For *right* censoring, that's reversed, the censoring time is when we *stop* observing.

Comment: Can you please extend your  answer that in `Right-censoring` , we observe only $Y_i=min(T_i,U_i)$

Comment: That's correct, I'll add it in.

Comment: In right-censoring if $T_i$ occurs within study period , then $T_i\le U_i\Rightarrow Y_i=T_i$ , if $T_i$ occurs after study period , then $U_i\le T_i\Rightarrow Y_i=U_i$  . Is it correct ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.